# Secure shared folders over VPN

Tags: windows-7, windows, security, vpn, shared-folders

I have machines both on windows 7 and windows 2008 R2.The VPN is up and running, and on all machines the VPN network is set to Home, and router network is set to public.

What I need, is a secure and convenient way to share folders. I have set up shared folders, and everything works fine.

However, the only solutions I have come up with are:

-Shared folders are accessed by everyone
This is not good, since even over the public network (not VPN) people can access the folders

-Password protect folders
This is not good either, as the folders seems to be accessed through all networks, but requiring a password. Someone could crack a password, and anyway its inconvenient to have passwords stored and whatnot.

What I would ideally want:
Shared folders are accessed freely, by ANYONE on the VPN network, and ONLY through the VPN network, without the password.

Note: Home/Work and Public network "advanced sharing" options seem completely bogus to me, since some settings seem to be universal for all network types. Other settings seem to not affect anything!

Answer (score 1):

Set the Windows Firewall to block all SMB Sharing traffic on the Router Network, and Allow for the VPN connection (Incoming Connections on Windows 7)